# BPGA - functional analysis

Tags: software-usage

I have been using BPGA to perform pan-genome analysis on my set of isolates. Now, I need the functional analysis as well. However I am having problem with the function, as the program says I am missing two files: usearch.exe (which I am sure is already present) and cog.udb, which I do not know what it is and where to find it.

Any suggestions on how to solve the error?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site Rob. Could you provide more information about your settings: You seem to use Windows, could you copy and paste the error message you get? Did you follow the [user guide](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bpgatool/files/BPGA%20User%20Manual.pdf/download) installation ?

Comment: The error is "File/s: cog.udb & usearch.exe not found. Copy missing files to current folder."
And yes, I followed the user guide for installation. Thanks!

Comment: Did you follow the installation steps of the linked user guide?

Comment: Yes, I followed the instruction